# Eclipse with java 1.8 failed to run javafx

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, java-8

I'm trying to run a simple JavaFX app in eclipse using java 1.8 (I don't have the option to use newer java version), my simple controller:

```
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
    import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

    public class MyController {
    
        @FXML private Canvas can;
    
        @FXML
        void buttonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        }
    }
```

and main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MyFxml.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("MyApp");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

my fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BoarderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller=MyController">
    <top>
        <ToolBar prefHeight="40.0" prefwidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <items>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonPressed" text="Press" />
            </item>
        </ToolBar>
    </top>
    <center>
        <Canvas fx:id="can" height="300.0" width="300.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

every time I try to run this I get

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

I have already added both `jfxrt.jar` and `jfxswt.jar` to a library and add it to the project and I've added permissions to javafx in the JRE but I keep getting this exception

Comment: Which Java 8 are you using? Oracle? OpenJDK? Which platform? That error message looks like it comes from a later Java version; are you certain you are using Java 8 at runtime?

Comment: @James_D I'm using eclipse's JavaSE-1.8 on Win64 and the javafx jars are from jre1.8.0_351

Comment: Does Eclipse's Java distribution include JavaFX? If you're talking about https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/, then I don't believe it does. Note that JavaFX was never part of Java SE, it's just that Oracle (and maybe some other vendors) included it for their own reasons. Since Java 11, Oracle no longer includes JavaFX, but other vendors do (e.g., Azul Zulu, BellSoft Liberica, etc.).

Comment: Don’t add jfxrt.jar to a project.  That does not include required JavaFX native components.  Instead, if you must use Java 8, then use Oracle Java 8 which already includes JavaFX, so no additional setup is necessary.